# How do I get multiplayer (Bluetooth or Game Center) working in TriggerFist

Tags: trigger-fist

I got [TriggerFist](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/trigger-fist/id531184261?mt=8) not too long ago and am really enjoying the gameplay – especially the wonderful AI. I then wanted to play with my friend. Both my friend and I have iPad Airs with iOS 7.0.6. Bluetooth is turned on.

I first tried the bluetooth multiplayer. Both my friend and I changed the dropdown box at the gamemode selection screen from singleplayer to bluetooth, then tapped next. Our devices found each other, I slected my friend's name when it appeared and my friend tapped accept when my invitation appeared on his screen, but we were not directed to a match. We tried again multiple times, some times with the roles reversed, but the game still stayed on the gamemode selection screen.

We then tried using the "Play w/ friend" option, where one of us invited the other to the game, but it still wouldn't work. After that, we tried both of us using the "Matchmaking" option at the same time, but we each got a different game, with different maps, of all bots.

Is there something I am meant to do that I've missed out on? I would really love to play the multiplayer, but I just can't seem to figure out how to get it working.

Comment: did you try looking here? "trigger-fist-45-acpank.wikia.com/‎"

Comment: @bob There doesn't appear to be anything relating specifically to multiplayer there, unfortunately.

Comment: sorry about that